# Is there a way to track who last accessed a resource through IDP in Identity Server?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm looking for a way to audit which users last accessed a particular resource that's tied into WSO2 Identity Server via the Identity Providers we add. Is this possible and if so, how would I be able to view the information in the WebUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see that information anywhere on the standard database model for Identity Server 4.  You'd have to keep track of that separately.

Comment: One of the considerations for IdentityServer is that it explicitly/purposefully separates authentication and authorization.  That ties into this question in that IdentityServer keeps as hands-off as possible in how the user is able to access a given resource, and everyone implements a role DB for their resources (checks to see that a given user has access).  Ultimately, we give and track access to specific apps in those types of databases.  This means that we keep track of usernames / identifiers in those as well, but as far as whether they are authenticated, that falls to the IDP in question.